# How to achieve Cin<< with spaces in c++

Tags: c++, cin

Does anyone know the best way to have 3 user inputs on one line for a console application.
for instance:

( command "search" time)

Comment: Use `std::getline`, *then* parse.

Comment: @Kerreck,use it 3 times? each part of the input goes to a variable.

Comment: It gets the whole line. If you want one line, use it once.

Comment: @KerrekSB,Thanks,I know how to use the getline function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will allow exactly three strings to be written on a line:

```
std::string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);

std::istringstream iss(line);
std::string command, param1, param2;

if (!(iss >> command >> param1 >> param2)) {
    std::cout << "Missing some input.\n";
} else if (std::cin >> std::ws && std::cin.peek() != EOF) }
    std::cout << "Too many parameters.\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "Ok.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach: **Overload `operator>>` to make it work with tuples**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<typename T>
T read(std::istream& is)
{
    T value;

    is >> value;

    return value;
}

template<typename... Ts>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is , std::tuple<Ts...>& tuple)
{
    tuple = std::make_tuple( read<Ts>(is)... );

    return is;
}
```

An example of its use could be:

```
int main()
{
    std::tuple<int,int> tuple;

    std::cin >> tuple;
}
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/h3Jeng) is a running example at ideone.